# Unity script error (The script don't inherit native class that can manage a script error )

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm currently making a quiz game using unity with guidance from youtube( this is the video that i follow https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G9QDFB2RQGA). now i'm stuck at the when i tried to add the answer script into buttons component (14:30). everytime i tried, the error message the script don't inherit native class pop out. have  been a day trying to find solution and i still can't find it. tried to change the script file name, class name to be identical, etc, but still cant add the script. there's no compiler error tho. anyone know whats wrong?

Answers.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Answers : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isCorrect = false;
    public Quizmanager quizmanager;

   public void Answers()
    {
        if (isCorrect)
        {
            Debug.log("Correct answer!");

        else
        {
                Debug.log("Wrong answer ~");
        }
    }
}
```

Quizmanager.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Quizmanager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Questions> QnA;
    public GameObject[] options;
    public int currentquestions;

    public Text Questiontxt;

    private void Start()

{
        generatequestion();
}
    public void correct()
    {
        QnA.RemoveAt[currentquestions];
        generatequestion();
    }
    void Setanswers()
    {
        for(inr 1=0; 1 <options.Length; int++)
        {
            options[i].GetComponent<AnswersScript>().isCorrect = false;
            options[i].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text = QnA[currentquestions].Answers[i];
            if(QnA[currentquestions].CorrectAnswer == i + 1)
            {
                options[i].GetComponent<AnswerScript>().isCorrect = true;
            }
        }
    }

    void generatequestion()
    {
        currentquestions = Random.Range(0, QnA.Count);

        Questiontxt.text = QnA[currentquestions].Question;
        Setanswers();

        
    }

}
```

Comment: Any compiler errors? And are you 100% that file names match?

Comment: Are you sure error code is about those 2 scripts you posted? can you post error?

Comment: Your code doesnt show you using the Answers class so there isn’t enough details to be helpful

Comment: no compiler error found. the cs file name is as shown. i have edited the question with the youtube video i used as reference.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues while using visual studio. The only way I managed to solve them was by creating a new script, and copying the class content (not the class name) into the new file and deleting the old file. The class name might change and the solution is a bit anticlimactic but it usually saves me from this issue.

Comment: still have the same error. looks like there some other prob with my codes. but i did try this, thanks